# How to retrieve tag name inside click event listener in Scala.js?

Tags: scala, scala.js

I have the following event listener:

```
dom.document.addEventListener("click", (e: MouseEvent) => {
      dom.console.log(e.target.tagName)
})
```

And I want to retrieve the target's `tagName`. Unfortunately, `e.target.tagName` does not work (compile error `value tagName is not a member of org.scalajs.dom.raw.EventTarget`). Any idea how I can fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a cast:

```
e.target.asInstanceOf[org.scalajs.dom.raw.Element].tagName
```

Comment: Yeah, this sort of thing is common when dealing with Events, because they are so loosely typed.  You often know for a fact that a given field is of a particular type, but *officially* it isn't necessarily so.  So you have to do a manual cast, to say "I know what this really is".